# A quick little riddle

Tags: lateral-thinking, situation

A man and a woman were driving in their car when it broke down. The man decided to go for help at a gas station a few miles back. He made sure nobody except for the woman was in the car, rolled all the windows up, and locked all of the sedan's doors. He went off, but when he came back, the woman was dead, and there was a stranger in the car. No physical damage was done to the car, so how did the stranger get in?

Comment: Shouldn't it be "He made sure nobody *except the woman* was in the car"?

Comment: @TTT try for an edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pretty well known riddle

> The stranger was a baby and the woman died in childbirth

Comment: Darn, okay I will come up with better ones in the future.

Comment: Man that's dark...  o.o

Comment: I read this one some years ago and it almost put me off lateral-thinking puzzles.

Comment: Slightly NSFW... wanna feel better, look up that video where a woman gives birth in the car on the way to the hospital.

Answer (score 3):

Lateral thinking answer:

> The man was an Uber driver and the woman was a customer (and thus a stranger). His wife was already dead prior to this incident.